# Programmatically extend a session's timeout in Laravel

Tags: laravel

**Background**

I have a laravel app which has a cart function. I store a random 64 byte string in a session (redis) and have a cart table in the database that has a column `masked_id`.

So essentially I save the products in the sql database and save a unique id in the session to identify it.

My issue is that I am aware that when this session times out, the customer will lose their cart.

I would like to extend the current session by now() + 2 hours every time the customer performs an action on their cart.

**So my question is:**

Is there a was in Laravel to programmatically extend a session timeout?

(I am aware I can change the default value in the config)

Comment: Any request made by the system should automatically extend the session timeout. I.e. if you wait 1.5 hours then hit refresh, your session is now valid for the next 2 hours (assuming 2 hours is the default timeout). So basically, any time they interact with their cart, this should automatically happen, unless that is only happening on the Client Side (JS), at which time you'll need to make a request to the Server Side (PHP), i.e. an AJAX request or similar. Or, use a "heartbeat" function like https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine or similar.

Comment: You can have a longer lasting cookie for this rather than relying on the session.